# sqlite GROUP items BY editor and HAVING date equals to MAX

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have 2 tables (see below schema) linked with a One To Many relationship :

`Item`

```
id, title, date, editor_id
1, item1, 10 1
2, item2, 20, 2
3, item3, 30, 2
4, item4, 40, 5
5, item5, 50, 5
6, item6, 60, 5
```

`Editor`

```
id, name
1, editor1
2, editor2
3, editor3
4, editor4
5, editor5
```

Items **4, 5 and 6 have the same editor**. Now i want to query all items, grouped by `editor_id` and having `date` = `MAX (date)`, like this :

```
count, item.title, editor.name, item.date
1, item1, editor1, 10
1, item2, editor2, 20
1, item3, editor3, 30
3, item6, editor5, 60  << because 60 (date for item6) is greater than 50 and 40 which are all in editor5
```

### Here is what i tried :

```
String having = MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DATE
                + " IN (SELECT MAX(" + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DATE + ") FROM "
                + MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_ITEM + ") ";
Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_ITEM, itemColumns,
                selection, null, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_EDITOR_ID, having,
                MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DATE + " DESC");
```

And my output is different to what i m expecting :

```
count, item.title, editor.name, item.date
1, item1, editor1, 10
1, item2, editor2, 20
1, item3, editor3, 30
3, item4, editor5, 40 << got 40 wich is not MAX of (40, 50, 60)
```

Hope it's clear.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite allows you to have an aggregation query that has columns in the `select` that are not aggregated and not in the `group by` clause.  SQLite chooses arbitrary values for this:  As the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#resultset) explains:

> Each non-aggregate expression in the result-set is evaluated once for
>   an arbitrarily selected row of the dataset.

My guess is that the resulting query has the form:

```
select count(*) as count, item.title, editor.name, item.date
. . . 
group by item.title, editor.name
. . .
```

The date being returned is *arbitrary*.  If you want the maximum date, then select `max(item.date)` instead:

```
select count(*) as count, item.title, editor.name, max(item.date) as "date"
. . . 
group by item.title, editor.name
. . .
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, It worked just after i have added `item.title` in group by clause, but I don't understand why ?